# What does "block" mean in Python 3?

Tags: python, indentation

I am a newbie in programming and trying to learn Python from automatetheboringstuff.com.
At the end of Chapter 2, the question below shows up. 
And even after I have go through the official answer, I still am clueless. 
Please help!

> Q:8. Identify the three blocks in this code:
>
> ```
> spam = 0
> if spam == 10:
>     print('eggs')
>     if spam > 5:
>         print('bacon')
>     else:
>         print('ham')
>     print('spam')
> print('spam')
> ```

Official answer:

> The three blocks are everything inside the if statement and the lines
>   `print('bacon')` and `print('ham')`.
>
> ```
> print('eggs')
> if spam > 5:
>     print('bacon')
> else:
>     print('ham')
> print('spam')
> ```

Comment: Don't know why this has got so many downvotes, personally I find the official question and answer not very helpful! In Python indention is critical, try changing the indentation of the last 2 `print` calls and see what happens to understand

Comment: Tried to delete the second last print indentation, but still not very successful in tackling the problem. Yet, very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new block begins every time you increase the indentation of a line, and ends just before the corresponding unindent.

```
spam = 0
if spam == 10:
    print('eggs')        # indent increased, block A
    if spam > 5:         # still block A
        print('bacon')   # still block A, indent increased, block B inside block A
    else:                # still block A, indent decreased, block B ended in line above
        print('ham')     # still block A, indent increased, block C inside block A
    print('spam')        # still block A, indent decreased, block C ended in line above
print('spam')            # indent decreased, block A ended in line above
```